# Are there packages/databases for incidence matrices of abstract polytopes

Tags: graph-theory, gap, polytopes, simplicial-complex, sagemath

I'd like to do computations with incidence matrices of abstract polytopes.
There's a database mentioned in this older post :

[what abstract regular polyhedra exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2002326/what-abstract-regular-polyhedra-exist)

but I don't see extract the incidence matrices from what's provided. I can find vertix-edge graphs
for a number of cases, but I need the full relations (vertix-edge, edge-face,...).
Are there any software packages (for GAP, Sage, ...) that have such a database and some utilities
to work with it? Even a small set of familiar examples (paltonic solids,...) would be good to start with.

Comment: Have you looked at `polymake` (which has a GAP interface), and its associated database?

Comment: I'll give that a try. It might be overkill for what I'm looking for. It's just the incidence matrices that I'm after; the geometric data is not necessary....Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: In addition: [The Atlas of Small Regular Polytopes](http://www.abstract-polytopes.com/atlas/index.html) by Michael Hartley, and [An Atlas of Polytopes for Small Almost Simple Groups](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~dleemans/polytopes/) by Laurence Vauthier and Dimitri Leemans.

Answer (score 2):

The incidence matrices in its generality, i.e. way beyond the regular solids only, is essentially my own elaboration. You might be welcome to look into my website at https://bendwavy.org/klitzing/home.htm which provides to my knowledge the most encompassing list of elaborated incidence matrices, even if all those have been worked out manually in the sequel of half a lifetime.

--- rk